# Extract only mid lanes from lanes coordinates Opencv Python

Tags: python, opencv

I am preparing a lane detection dataset which I will be training on my UNET architecture. I have downloaded the dataset from here.
Each dictionary in `ground_truth_labels.txt` have the structure:

```
{
  "lanes": [
        [-2, -2, -2, -2, 632, 625, 617, 609, 601, 594, 586, 578, 570, 563, 555, 547, 539, 532, 524, 516, 508, 501, 493, 485, 477, 469, 462, 454, 446, 438, 431, 423, 415, 407, 400, 392, 384, 376, 369, 361, 353, 345, 338, 330, 322, 314, 307, 299],
        [-2, -2, -2, -2, 719, 734, 748, 762, 777, 791, 805, 820, 834, 848, 863, 877, 891, 906, 920, 934, 949, 963, 978, 992, 1006, 1021, 1035, 1049, 1064, 1078, 1092, 1107, 1121, 1135, 1150, 1164, 1178, 1193, 1207, 1221, 1236, 1250, 1265, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2],
        [-2, -2, -2, -2, -2, 532, 503, 474, 445, 416, 387, 358, 329, 300, 271, 241, 212, 183, 154, 125, 96, 67, 38, 9, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2],
        [-2, -2, -2, 781, 822, 862, 903, 944, 984, 1025, 1066, 1107, 1147, 1188, 1229, 1269, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2]
       ],
  "h_samples": [240, 250, 260, 270, 280, 290, 300, 310, 320, 330, 340, 350, 360, 370, 380, 390, 400, 410, 420, 430, 440, 450, 460, 470, 480, 490, 500, 510, 520, 530, 540, 550, 560, 570, 580, 590, 600, 610, 620, 630, 640, 650, 660, 670, 680, 690, 700, 710],
  "raw_file": "path_to_clip"
}
```

When I visualize the lanes, this is what I get:

```
lanes = annots["lanes"]
h_samples = annots["h_samples"]
lane_vis = [[(x, y) for (x, y) in zip(lane, h_samples) if x >= 0] for lane in lanes]
img_vis = img.copy()
for lane in lane_vis:
    cv2.polylines(img_vis, np.int32([lane]), isClosed=False, color=(255,255,255), thickness=15)
```

[image]

[image]

So, how can I make sure I visualize the 2 main lanes only, i.e. the current lane (left and right) on which the car is right now, not others. Is there any way to distinguish and filter out only the main 2 lanes?

I know something is to be done with `lanes` key but I don't know which list of `lanes` corresponds to which one, and in each image the lanes differs.

This is the repository from where I downloaded this dataset.

https://github.com/TuSimple/tusimple-benchmark/tree/master/doc/lane_detection 
https://github.com/IrohXu/lanenet-lane-detection-pytorch

Comment: if you got the lines as functions you could calculate which of all the lines are closest to the vertikal mid of the image from left and from right. I don't know if this can fail with certain situations but you could try it out

Comment: @TheodorPeifer sounds good, I also tried a different approach, I calculated the sum of each lane and got the largest 2 sums, so like, according to me, the 2 greatest sum would be the 2 middle lanes because those will have greater pixel values. It did work but obviously it fails with certain situations where the left most or right most is more wide lane or because of some distortion.

Comment: then you could maybe combine both ideas for more certency

Comment: another approach could be to calculate the angles between each line and a vertical line. The two lines with the smallest angle should be the lines of your current lane